# Confirmation icon is misaligned on the Join Company page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, design

When you visit a link to join the company and Associate your profile with that company, the icon with a tick mark between profile photo and company image - is broken.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to have since been addressed, as I can't reproduce it in Chrome, Firefox or Edge in Windows 10, and my teammate is unable to reproduce on Chrome or Safari in OSX.  If you're still seeing the issue, please update your report to include which browser and OS you are using.

note: if you want to try reproducing, you can remove yourself from the company page by going to [your preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences) and clicking "Revoke permission".  Then, ask the company page admin to re-invite you.

[image]